# Loading an exact location in a div from Google Maps

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to the concept of using Google maps in my website.I have gotten this script to load a particular location in a div in my webpage. However, the desired location does not load into my page.

---

Say, I want to load the location `BIT Main Bldg Patna, Bihar, India 12 m E` in the div whenever we open the page. However, the result is not exact and we need to zoom in few more layers.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Geocoding Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var address = 'BIT Main Bldg Patna, Bihar, India 12 m E';

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
       zoom: 8
   });

   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
   }, 
   function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
         });
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
      else {
         // Google couldn't geocode this request. Handle appropriately.
      }
   });

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

---

You may see the exact desired result by inputting `BIT Main Bldg Patna, Bihar, India 12 m E` in the output text box in [this](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#geocoding_simple) page. What's the mistake here ?

Comment: you can trying increasing the "zoom" maybe to something like 18 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your page display a map like the one on the page you linked to, you need to alter the options you're supplying in your map constructor. Change the `zoom` attribute to 15 or 16 and `mapTypeId` to `google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP`, and your map will look more like what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

try the following :

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       zoom: 15
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would reorganize your markup. The script should either be in the head section or after the `</body>` tag so that your function executes after all the elements are properly loaded in the browser DOM.

Create a function like

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function initialise()
{
   var address = 'BIT Main Bldg Patna, Bihar, India 12 m E';

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
       zoom: 10 //to get to a desirable zoom level change this value
   });

   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
   }, 
   function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
         });
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
      else {
         // Google couldn't geocode this request. Handle appropriately.
      }
   });
}
   </script>
```

Then in your `<body>` tag you should use a onload event to execute the script.

```
<body onload="initialise()">
```